Found black mold on drywall
We have only been in our home for 4 months. Built 1970. I'm getting ready to skim coat the walls of the living room. I'm prepping the surface and I had a spot where the drywall got knocked off when removing the baseboards. I'm vacuuming and picking away the excess when I notice there's black mold on the paper facing the inside of the wall...
How concerned should I be about this? Other side of this wall is just the exterior. Nothing seems moist. The wood I can see seems old but not rotted. There is a rectangular patch further up the wall where I'm guessing a wall AC unit may have been.  I'm assuming this is from an old leak and it hasn't really spread. I have a humidity monitor and our indoor humidity is good at 37 percent.
I found one other small bit of mold on another area of baseboard across the room. I cleaned it with bleach and then sanded the area a few days later and no sign of further penetration of the mold in that spot.
Would painting this section of wall with KILZ original be sufficient or do I need to do some more digging to see how extensive this is. And if so, how do I go about patching it up?

Are you sure it is mold, or just black tar paper used for insulation

@Traveler Ah, great point. I'm not familiar with it.

If bleach kills it it is mold

the first picture looks like tar paper

That looks like mold and roach droppings.  The pictures indicate that there was /is some water infiltration inside the wall.

@RMDman Yeah, I see what you mean. There was an AC unit right above this area. It's been sealed up for a long time. I cut out some more drywall and the mold is inside the gypsum but it's not too extensive. My partner doesn't want to spend the money on mold remediation right now and just wants me to cut out the section with mold, patch, and keep skimming the walls. Says we'll deal with it later. What's your opinion on me doing that.

@ Alex, If you remove the drywall with any mold and spray down the wood with 50/50 bleach and water, then let it dry before any new drywall goes up, you're good.  There should not be any issues.
